# How to GET the column width in a Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Is there a way to get the width of all treeview columns of a tk.treeview?

I know how to set the width, but I would like to save the user's custom changes in a list after they exit the window so I can recall it after a restart.

So far I have everything running, I'm just searching (and couldn't find) an answer on how to get the column width.

Here's a minimal code example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Minimal Treeview")


treeview = ttk.Treeview(
    root,
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
    height="10")
treeview.column(0, width=300, anchor="w")
treeview.column(1, width=500, anchor="w")
treeview.column(2, width=60, anchor="w")
treeview.pack()


def on_exit(event):
    # Desired code:
    # column_width = treeview.columnswidth
    # column_width holds something like [233, 500, 48]
    print("Exit Program")


# Before exiting, user changes the column width manually with the mouse
root.bind("<Destroy>", on_exit)
root.mainloop()
```

Every help is appreciated! :-) Thank you very much in advance and enjoy your coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the `column()` with the column name and the option `'width'`

```
print(treeview.column('col1', 'width'))

# => 300 (returns the column width as an integer)
```

Update: The error you're getting is caused because the `treeview` widget is destroyed before you can call `column()` - see below for a fix

```
# modify the 'on_exit' function as follows
def on_exit():  # no event binding means no 'event' param
    print(treeview.column('col1', 'width'))  # get col width as needed
    # put whatever else you want to do before exiting here...
    print('Exit Program')
    root.quit()  # exit


# replace the event binding with this protocol handler
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_exit)
root.mainloop()
```

The protocol handler `'WM_DELETE_WINDOW'` is called whenever the window it's bound to is destroyed. In this case, it will call your `on_exit` function when you attempt to close the window. You will still need to explicitly quit the program, so that's also handled in `on_exit` with `root.quit()`

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Have you tried this inside of the code? I'm getting an error:
.....ttk.py", line 297, in _val_or_dict
    res = tk.call(*(args + options))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!treeview"

Comment: Oh I see the problem here. It doesn't work inside of the on_exit function, but it for sure does in the rest of the code. Do you have any idea for a workaround. I'm very sorry that I'm missing the fundamental understanding here :/

Comment: Hi there - sorry for the slow reply. That error is likely due to the fact that `treeview` can't be accessed by the `on_exit` function in its current scope. Try adding the line `global treeview` inside the function right after `def on_exit` and before the call to `treeview.column('col1', 'width')`

Comment: Jumping in again to say that you'll need to call the `column()` method once for each column to get all the widths (if that's what you want). Alternatively, (I think) you can also get an iterable of the column IDs and just loop over those!

Comment: Hey again, @JRiggles. Yes iterate over the ID's works instead of using their names. However adding `global treeview` does not change the produced error. It also makes no difference when declaring the global outside of the function. :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show me exactly what you’re doing that’s producing that error?

Comment: I'm having my above example code, except these two lines are added right after and inside the `on_exit(event)` function: `global treeview` and `print(treeview.column('col1', 'width'))`. I then run the script in Sublime Text 4126. The root window opens and I see the treeview columns with nothing inside. When I press the red x (apple 10.15.7), Sublime shows the error in it's Console. It did not print the column width.

Comment: The issue appears to be caused by the fact that the treeview widget is being destroyed before it can be queried. I've edited my answer - hopefully this helps!

Comment: The Edit works like a charm. Thanks for not just answering ONE question, but TWO! My upvote has been saved for when I reach my initial reputation (newcomer here ...). Thanks again for sharing your knowledge and time. `print("Best wishes")`

Comment: Happy to help - glad it worked out! Happy coding to ya.